# Maven-war-plugin - customize filter delimitters in webResources

Tags: maven, filter, war, delimiter

I have a context.xml file containing this resource :

```
<Resource name="${jndi.name}" auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
          url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@${db.server}:${db.port}:${db.name}"
          username="${db.user}" password="${db.pwd}" maxActive="500" maxIdle="60"
          maxWait="-1"/>
```

and while processing webapp resources maven-war-plugin filter that file :

```
<plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <dependentWarExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar,**/web.xml</dependentWarExcludes>
          <webResources>
            ....
            <resource>
              <directory>src/main/webapp/META-INF</directory>
              <targetPath>META-INF</targetPath>
              <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            ....
          </webResources>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

and the result is :

```
<Resource name="myjndiname" auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
          url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@${db.server}:${db.port}:${db.name}"
          username="user" password="pass" maxActive="500" maxIdle="60"
          maxWait="-1"/>
```

the URL part is not filtered, as '@' is interpreted as a delimiter. Delimiter param can be customized for maven-resources-plugin but i have no idea how to do it for maven-war-plugin !

Please help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try escaping the at-sign like `\@`

Comment: I tried using back slash as you advised but problem still there :
    `<Resource name="myjndiname" auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
          url="jdbc:oracle:thin:\@${db.server}:${db.port}:${db.name}"
          username="user" password="pass" maxActive="500" maxIdle="60"
          maxWait="-1"/>`

Comment: It's a bug in Maven Shared Filtering. If you create a Jira issue at https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MSHARED/component/13380 I can have a look at it. I'd like to do a release soon. Right now there's only 1 open issue, but that requires a bit of redesign (so a 2.0). Maybe I can include a bugfix for this issue.

Comment: This unittest passes, not sure where or when it was fixed: http://svn.apache.org/r1571030

Comment: Thank you for your clarifications, I though that is me who screwed up something ^^